# How to align a group of text to be on the left side of a page

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I move all the (left1,left2,left3) to be on the very left side of the page (given that the page is 8.5in x 11in with margins 0.5in on each side) like the image above? with the right side text to be on the very right? currently it is only staying 0.5in next to the right side text like so,

[image]

I tried adding a float left to the `<p>` but that didn't seem to work and the left side is still staying 0.5 inches next to the right side in the footer.

Not sure how to proceed with this and need some guidance.

```css
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    #footer {
      position: running(footer);
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size:12px;
      color : #000000;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .footertext {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size:8px;
      color : #000000;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-right: 0.5in;
    }
    
    .leftside {
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footertext">
      <p>left1</p>
      <p>left2</p>
      <p>left3</p>
    </div>
    <span class="page">a random sentence</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You not set properly text-align for footer, that is why error is occured

```css
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    #footer {
      position: running(footer);
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size:12px;
      color : #000000;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: left; // look like there is an error
    }

    .footertext {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size:8px;
      color : #000000;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-right: 0.5in;
    }
    
    .leftside {
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footertext">
      <p>left1</p>
      <p>left2</p>
      <p>left3</p>
    </div>
    <span class="page">a random sentence</span>
  </div>
```

Now your text is in the left side

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, you needed to make a new property for the right side `.page` class and float it right and also add `float: left;` to your .footertext class

```css
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    #footer {
      position: running(footer);
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size:12px;
      color : #000000;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .footertext {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size:8px;
      color : #000000;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-right: 0.5in;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .leftside {
        float: left;
    }
    
    .page{
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="footer">
    <div class="footertext">
      <p>left1</p>
      <p>left2</p>
      <p>left3</p>
    </div>
    <span class="page">a random sentence</span>
  </div>
```